# converting desktop application to multi user desktop application

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

i have been working on desktop application using sql express database which can be used on single computer only.
Now the scenario is that i need to extend the application to multiple computers.
For that i need sql express as centralized database and the whole application should access the database and use it.
Now my problem is that i have no idea where to begin with.
i have been goggling but could not find proper answer to it.
please help me with the task.
any sort of tutorials or links can be useful.

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 4):

***Best Place to begin with:***

**[How to configure SQL Server to allow remote connections - Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277#method1)**

And after configuring all this, just install your `application` on all `terminals` with `database` on your server.

Use the following **connection-string**:

```
"Data Source=Your_Server_Name\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Your_Database_Name; integrated security=true"
```

> Here are some steps you'll need to follow:
>
> **Enable remote connections for SQL Server 2005 Express or SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition**
>
> You must enable remote connections for each instance of SQL Server
>   2005 that you want to connect to from a remote computer. To do this,
>   follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Surface Area
>      Configuration.
> 2. On the SQL Server 2005 Surface Area Configuration page, click Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> 3. On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, expand Database Engine, click Remote Connections, click Local
>      and remote connections, click the appropriate protocol to enable for
>      your environment, and then click Apply.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> **Note:** Click OK when you receive the following message:
>
> Changes to Connection Settings will not take effect until you
>   restart the Database Engine service.
>
> 4. On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, expand Database Engine, click Service, click Stop, wait until
>      the MSSQLSERVER service stops, and then click Start to restart the
>      MSSQLSERVER service.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> **Enable the SQL Server Browser Service**
>
> Provides SQL Server connection information to client computers. To
>   enable the SQL Server Browser service, follow these steps:
>
> 5. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Surface Area
>      Configuration.
> 6. On the SQL Server 2005 Surface Area Configuration page, click Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections.
> 7. On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, click SQL Server Browser, click Automatic for Startup type, and
>      then click Apply.
>
> **Note:** When you click the Automatic option, the SQL Server Browser service starts automatically every time that you start Microsoft
>   Windows.
>
> 8. Click Start, and then click OK.
>
> [image]
>
> **Windows Firewall – Turn off Firewall**
>
> 9. Open the Control Panel, click on Windows Firewall OR click Start, click Run, type firewall.cpl, and then click OK.. Once open, Go to the
>      Exceptions Tab. Just scroll down and check whether you can see
>      sqlservr.exe is added in the list and also its checkbox is checked.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> 10. If not, click Add Programs button, then click the Browse button and locate the sqlservr.exe inside the Program Files > Microsoft SQL
>       Server > MSSQL.1 > MSSQL > BINN > sqlservr.exe. The path might be
>       different depends on the SQL Server 2005 installation. So find the
>       sqlservr.exe and add it in the exceptions list. Then Click OK.
>
> [image]
>
> 11. The second workaround for the SQLExpress connection problem is to enable the TCP/IP protocol in the SQL Server Configuration Manager >
>       SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLExpress. On
>       the right hand-side pane, right click on your TCP/IP protocol and
>       choose Enable. You have to restart the SQLExpress Service again for
>       this change to take effect.
>
> [image]
>
> ***Restart the services and Now you can connect the remote system with the server and access the data from the SQL Server Express 2005.***

**References**:

- **[How to Configure SQL Server 2005 to Allow Remote Connections](http://www.sqlserverclub.com/essentialguides/how-to-configure-sql-server-2005-to-allow-remote-connections.aspx)**
- **[Configuring Remote Connections For SQL Server Express 2005](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Enable_Remote_Connections_SQLServerExpress.aspx)**

Comment: Thank you very much for the start.hope i will solve my problem